# Android Reminder app

Tags: android, android-intent

How to create a reminder application from android by using a datepicker and timepicker ?

I create a sample app without using datpicker.But I need to know it using a datpicker andd timpicker

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       //for using this you need to import java.util.Calendar;

    // add minutes to the calendar object
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);               
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);


    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("title","Title of our Notification");
    alarmintent.putExtra("note","Description of our  Notification");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID,
            alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just drag and drop the widget date picker and Time picker
Make there object like

```
DatePicker dt=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

Now you can use dt to get date,month and year like

```
dt.getMonth();
dt.getYear();
dt.getDay();
```

thats is how you can use Date picker similarly time picker .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this demo for **[datepicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)** and this for [timepicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) to allow user to selecte the date and time and store them in variable and instead setting the static number to the Calendar set values from the stored variable.

And the rest of the code will remain the same.

If you want to use any fancy date and time picker just go to this open-source project they have usee WheelView to show date and time like iPhone style here **[AndAlarm](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Clock/andalarm/Catalogandalarm.htm)**